# MySQL bulk update succeeds but not reflected on all

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I have a game where I use (`Spring`, `Hibernate` and `MySQL 5.7`) in the back-end. At the end of each game, I execute a native query to bulk update balance of the winners. Most games the update executes successfully for all winners, but for a few games I face the problem of updating the balance for most of them except for one or two (random). The update doesn't throw **an error** and as said Most of the winners' balance is updated successfully. Here is the method in my `DAO` (I summed it up) with the native `query`:

```
@Override
public Integer addAmountToPlayerBalance(List<Long> playerIds, Double amount, Long gameId) {
        try 
        {
            StringBuilder queryNative = new StringBuilder();
            queryNative.append("update game_player_user set balance = ifnull(balance,0) + :amount where id in (:playerIds)");


            Session session = teleEM.unwrap(Session.class);
            org.hibernate.Query query = session.createSQLQuery(queryNative.toString());
            query.setParameter("amount", amount);
            query.setParameterList("playerIds", playerIds);
            int numOfUpdatedRecords = query.executeUpdate();
            return numOfUpdatedRecords;
        } 
        catch (NoResultException e) 
        {
            return null;
        }
}
```

**Notes**:

**1)** I added the code for returning the number of updated records a week ago but it hasn't occurred on production since then. but as I said, it happens occasionally.

**2)** The list of player Ids includes all of the winners even in the games where the issue appears.

**3)** The amount is double but rounded to 2 decimal places.

Comment: At least if you are using InnoDB, MySQL will execute the whole query or nothing at all (and if you are using MyISAM, it will only stop if an error occurs, which you say doesn't happen). There is not enough information to tell you what went wrong. I'd check if your list contains all ids you are expecting (add logs, enable/check general query log); check if the player id might not be in game_player_user (maybe it gets added later) or if something else updates that table (do e.g. losers lose money and the ids are in both lists? Triggers?). Do these rows/players have something in common?

Comment: I'm using InnoDB .. and I checked but there is nothing happening on the column at the same time of winners update .. also couldn't detect any resemblance between the data of these players .. however, this column is defined as double and for some players (some in the case mentioned in OP and some others) , the balance has too many decimal digits (e.g. 12.3200000000000001)

Comment: So is there anything that comes up to your mind that I should check? should the column be defined as numeric with 2 decimal place instead of double? could this affect the bulk update in a random way like this?

Comment: The digits are a sideeffect of how doubles are stored (not limited to databases); for amounts, `decimal` is the proper choice though. But it should be unrelated to your problem. Apart from a thorough code inspection, I'd suggest to log whatever you can (sql query log, history triggers, adding an `on update`-timestamp-column, print/write the list to a file, maybe add a `select count(*) from game_player_user where id in (:playerIds)` (before, maybe additionally after the update) and throw an exception if it doesnt match the list count, ...) to check for any inconsistencies.

Comment: Thanks .. I'll see what options can help to trace the problem better and update my question or add a solution to it if I find one.